# Rails - How to overcome repetitive REST controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, scaffolding

I've finally started making a Rails app from scratch and I'm getting the hang of it, but the only problem is that making all the models/controllers is getting really repetitive and totally throwing the whole DRY concept out of the window as I'm basically copying controllers and renaming them/adding/disabling fields. I have:

Projects
People
Tasks
Messages

etc and the first three need to pretty much have the same layout and CRUD. Is the only way of not having to manually create all of the actions/views each time scaffolding? If so, what other things does scaffolding generate that I need to be aware of. I've been cautious of using it in the past because I wanted to know how my application worked in the tutorials.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I asked: ` Is the only way of not having to manually create all of the actions/views each time scaffolding? If so, what other things does scaffolding generate that I need to be aware of. I've been cautious of using it in the past because I wanted to know how my application worked in the tutorials.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion scaffolding is not for new rails programmers, it should only be used after you figured out rails yourself and with a criticizing approach. It may generate whole files that you have no need, define unneeded routes etc...

You can have a look at the full details of what scaffold creates [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding)

As for the repetitive controllers you are making I could suggest using the gem [InheritedResources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/) which eliminates a lot of this duplication (at least while you are at the basic CRUD controller operations)

InheritedResources sets the basic controller index/show/destroy/create/edit actions for you, all you have to do is to inherit from it using:

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

In case you have to, you can override actions by defining them yourself.

Comment: Thank you that's great! I understand how CRUD works but I'm still hesitant to using scaffolding because I feared what you confirmed that it generated a lot of files. I'll take a look at that gem!

Answer (score 1):

It's an excellent point. You generally want to keep your controllers as thin as possible, and certainly thinner than what the scaffolding gives you.

The way I like to think of the scaffolding is that it's good to use for your first feature in a new Rails app as an example of the current best practices and things you might want to know about. After that, however, write your controllers yourself, and factor out any duplication.

For additional ideas, you might want to read/watch...

- [Objects on Rails](http://objectsonrails.com/)
- [Hexagonal Rails](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGN4RFkhH2M)
- [Architecture the Lost Years](http://confreaks.com/videos/759-rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years)

Comment: Thank you that's what I suspected. It just seems a waste having to make 5+ controllers that practically do the same thing for different models.